# Jquery datatable features shows in delay

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `datatable` ver. 1.10.9.

The `datatable` drop-down and other features of data-table plug-in shows after the table is shown and it doesn't look good that way.

What can I do in such situation?

Comment: Please post your initialization code or create an example on jsFiddle, without it your question is at risk of closing. See [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thanks, I know how to init datatable - so posting a jsfiddle won't help me..
What i have asked is- if someone know of a way to force the datatable plugin features to load when the table is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I did is hiding the table and when all the page is loaded show it.

Like that:

> CSS file:

```
#dt{ display:none }
```

> in the js file i call on callback function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var dt = $('#dt').DataTable({
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
```